# Importing produtcs with images from .csv file error

Tags: magento-2.1, product-images, import-products

When I try to import a .csv file with products and images I got this error:

```
Imported resource (image) could not be downloaded from external 
resource due to timeout or access permissions
```

In the .csv file the image is stored without **'/'** for example : **image.png**
Before using the import function I've uploaded the image in `pub/media/import`
I've also tried to log the error in the **exception.log** file and it says `pub/media/import/a/g/agricolture.png` not found or has read restriction.
Why **a/g** if in the **.csv** Have I only the filename?

The image has 755 permission.

Answer (score 0):

After selecting the file to import, enter the relative path following Images File Directory:

```
/pub/media/import
```

For more info: http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/data-import-product-images.html

Comment: Now the products with the images are correctly imported but the error is still displayed

Answer (score 0):

For me this setting worked:

1. In the CSV file, only included image name. E.g. image-021.jpg
2. Uploaded images in: `pub/media/import/`
3. In Magento Admin import
   page, I left the text field: `Images File Directory` blank.

When I upload my images to a sub dir in `import` e.g. in a directory called `mydir` this will be my images path `pub/media/import/mydir`. However, I still only write the images names in the CSV file.

I only specify `mydir` when in the import page text field `Images File Directory` making it look like this: `/mydir`

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be occur due to various errors. In my case, I made all my image files name to lowercase and used only letters and numbers in file name. Then import worked perfectly. Note: Make sure all your files have 777 permission.

Now if you need to rename all your files to lowercase using command line (cmd), move (cd) to image directory and use following code

```
ls | while read upName; do loName=`echo "${upName}" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`; mv "$upName" "$loName"; done
```

Hope this will help